# calling functions of the application via javascript from embeded browser?

Tags: c#, javascript

I have an embeded browser in C# application which I am displaying static webpages in. Can I call a function of the app by pressing a button in a webpage inside of the embeded browser via javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [`WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx).  Set a class to the `ObjectForScripting` property and its public properties and methods will be available to JavaScript via `window.external`.

**Example (from MSDN)**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Permissions;

[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
    private Button button1 = new Button();

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        button1.Text = "call script code from client code";
        button1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
        webBrowser1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
        Controls.Add(button1);
        Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;
        webBrowser1.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
        webBrowser1.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
        webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
        // Uncomment the following line when you are finished debugging.
        //webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

        webBrowser1.DocumentText =
            "<html><head><script>" +
            "function test(message) { alert(message); }" +
            "</script></head><body><button " +
            "onclick=\"window.external.Test('called from script code')\">" +
            "call client code from script code</button>" +
            "</body></html>";
    }

    public void Test(String message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message, "client code");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("test",
            new String[] { "called from client code" });
    }

}
```